# How to determine gender of a young hop plant?

Tags: hops, growing-hops

I'm looking for some info on this for reasons of domestication of wild hops that grow around. I need to sort out male plants from the batches I pick up in the wild -- currently I'm just waiting until some flowers appear and prune male hops after that, but this process is actually not very fast nor resource efficient...

Q: Is there any possible reliable method to tell apart small male and female hop plants before they start flowering?

Thanks!

Comment: Got a PCR machine? http://www.agriculturejournals.cz/publicFiles/53774.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer; no. (Unless the parent was old school and painted the room blue or pink.)

However, for a flowering plant:

> Cones are the female flower. The male flowers appear as small clusters
>   of round buds

from http://www.homebrewtalk.com/showthread.php?t=405875

First comment on page has a pic of both.

Comment: After a lot of additional googling and with having no PCR machine, I'm accepting this as impossible.

Comment: Have you tried taking it out of the ground and looking between it's hind roots? :p ... I have been drinking...